# Chunk ItemReader processing multiple files

Tags: jberet

I need to process multiple input files through chunk. Before I rebuild the wheel, is there a BeanIO ItemReader out there that can do this? Or another approach?

Comment: I'm not aware of any, but I haven't worked with BeanIO for long time so my knowledge is stale. You may want to pre-precess these files to combine them so you are dealing with one file.  If one file turns out too big, you can have multiple steps with each step handling one file.  Not sure if you can have one single step, with multiple partitions, with each partition handling one file. I think it should work if you configure partition plan properties to specify the input for each partition.

Comment: Is Jberet still being supported?

Comment: yes, same as before.

Comment: That is great news.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a batchlet to process through the list of files by programmatically creating a chunk job and executing it.